# Fetch file from database server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm building a project where the front end is `react` and the backend is `ruby on rails` and uses a postgres DB. A required functionality is the ability for users to export a large datasets.

I have the following code snippet that creates a CSV and stores it on the database server.

```
query = <<-SQL
    COPY (SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDERS.STORE_ID = ? OFFSET ? LIMIT ?) to '/temp/out.txt' WITH CSV HEADER
SQL
query_result = Order.find_by_sql([query, store_id.to_i, offset.to_i, 1000000])
```

How would I be able to retrieve that file to send to the front end. I've seen examples that use `copy_data` and `get_copy_data` but I couldn't get it to work with parameterized query. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your approach:

1. `COPY` doesn't support parameters, so you will have to construct the complete query string on the client side (beware of SQL injection).
2. `COPY ... TO 'file'` requires superuser rights or membership in the `pg_write_server_files` role.

   Don't even think of running an application as a superuser.

   Even without that, allowing client code to create files on the database server opens you the risk of denial-of-service through a full file system.

I think that the whole idea is ill-conceived. If you have a large query result, the database server will automatically use temporary files if an intermediate result won't fit into memory. Keep it simple.

Comment: can you offer a better solution for exporting large data sets?

Comment: Just run a simple `SELECT`. The result is streamed to the client.

Comment: the OP is asking about exporting to CSV for a million records. Are you suggesting having the front end (react) handle the creation of the csv file?

Comment: @jim Yes. Is that a problem?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe wouldn't it be less efficient if the front end needs to convert over a million rows to csv? Also, it may not work on older browsers

Comment: Perhaps, if Ruby is a very inefficient programming language. Are there no options in Ruby to read a result set in chunks, to avoid memory problems?